# how to apply factory design pattern on Angular App. Is this a good idea to use a factory design pattern in an angular app

Tags: angular, design-patterns

I want to use a different design pattern in my angular app. please suggest any design pattern which is good for performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer the below link for getting the example how to use factory design pattern. Basically this concept is not of angular but typescript.
[Factory Design Pattern](https://blog.fullstacktraining.com/factory-pattern-in-typescript/)

And when it comes to whether you should use it or not.
Then it depends on your requirement and your object creation.

If your object creation is complex and you need to apply different logics while creating the object then you can use this pattern for generating the object.

But there is not such saying that says that it is always good to use factory design pattern.
Many a times you just overkill the usage where it was not even required.